# How do you create rules for jquery form validate plugin with names that are arrays?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins, validation

Does anyone know how to create the rules for the jquery form validate plugin when you have a name attribute that is an array?

eg.

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" id="firstId" value="1" />One <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" id="secondId" value="2" />One <br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            data: {
                required: true, minlength: 1
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Problem is that the 'data' syntax is incorrect. Using data[] or data\[\] is also invalid. I've only gotten it to work with

```
$('#firstId').rules('add', { required: true, minlength: 1});
```

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to wrap the name of the input (in this case data[]) in quotes

```
$('#myform').validate({
  rules : {
    'data[]': { required: true, minlength: 1 }
  }
});
```

see the documentation here for Field with complex names (Brackets Dots): http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
$('#myform').validate({
  rules : {
    'data[]': { required: true, minlength: 1 
    }
  }
}
);
```

I don't know if it will work, give it a shot.