# jQuery validate plugin with a minimum of 2 elements from a single array name

Tags: jquery, arrays, validation

I have a list of input `type="file"` with their names as `list[]`. Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197782/how-do-you-create-rules-for-jquery-form-validate-plugin-with-names-that-are-array), I was able to make the rules and messages working in my jQuery.
But I do need at least 2 elements of list[] to be filled and adding the rule `required: true` only works for the irst element of the list, any idea how do I do that?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: Nobody? I'm sure there's a way around as we can we use the '[]' in the name. I've tried 'list[0]' without any results =/

Comment: I think the problem I'm facing is that all the elements have the same name: name="list[]", then the Javascript can't access to the list[number] I want, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right I fixed the problem.
I saw [there](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php) that the key in a name property is optional in HTML, but I thought I could **NOT** specify the array key in the array name of an HTML form element.

So I just changed some PHP/HTML code -a very few words actually-, just to specify the key of each element created.
Then, I just used `'list[--NUMBER--]': { required: true, accept: "jpe?g|gif|png" }`, to make my fields mandatory :)

Hope it will help some people around.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

try using something like:

```
{ required: true, minlength:2 }
```

or even without "required" rule